# display none and :has

Tags: css, css-selectors

does :has respond positively or negatively to display: none. Meaning if you have an element, with display none on it, would :has still see that there is an element present? I assume it would since there is an element there. But I might need to combine it with:

```
:not([style*="display: none"])
```

just confirming the behavior

Comment: Can you be a little more concrete about what it is you're after? What have you tried and what's not working? Add a [mcve] if you need

Comment: This wasn't a matter of what was tried or not, I couldn't find in the docs how it responds to display - the answer in the page now suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display` property does not change behavior of selectors, as it doesn't change the DOM tree, so yes it would still work

like if you have

```html
<div>
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

```
div:has(p) {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5rem;
}
p {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "display:none" we set as inline style at any code that element will be hidden.

```html
<style>
.wrp:has(p[style='display:none']){
    display:block !important;
}
.wrp p:not([style='display:none']){
    color:red;
}
</style>

<div class='wrp'>
  <p style="display:none">1 This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>2 This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The other answer was correct, but your answer is good info to know if I wanted to check the display:none value. Thanks for the response. My reputation isn't high enough to upvote your answer though!